# How do I make pulseaudio or pipewire auto-detect newly plugged in audio devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

I've been having some issues with my audio devices on Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS. If headphones are plugged in before booting, it is recognized by the system and works fine. However, if I plug in a new device (it's the same problem whether it's plugged in on front or back ports) while my PC is on, it doesn't get recognized automatically. In order to use it, I have to restart pulseaudio (or pipewire which I've just switched to but which didn't change anything). After restarting, it works without any problems.

My question is therefore: is there any better way to do this? I would preferably want it to automatically detect new devices being plugged in so I don't have to manually restart pulseaudio or pipewire.